# Inserting valid email into a table in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I want to write code to give username and password from a user and check the format of the email. Email's format is expression(string or number or both)@string.string. If the email's format is correct I must enter this email and password into a table in my database. Could you help me to write the correct code, my code does not work?

```
import re
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database='username_password')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
print("Enter email address: ")
email=input()
print("enter password: ")
password=input()
regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'  

def check(email):   

    if(re.search(regex,email)):   
        return("Valid Email")
    
    else:   
        print("Invalid Email")
        print("Enter correct format: expression@string.string")
        print("Enter email address: ")
        email=input()

if __name__ == '__main__' :     
    check(email)
    if check(email)=="Valid Email":
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO _info Values (email,password)")
        cnx.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a method who's job is well defined, for now it can return a string, or input a new email, one option is that the method only return a vlaid email

Also check how to insert in db, you need to pass the values at some point

```py
def get_valid_email():
    regex = r'^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
    email = input("Enter email address: ")
    while not re.fullmatch(regex, email):
        print("Invalid Email")
        print("Enter correct format: expression@string.string")
        email = input("Enter email address: ")

    return email


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                                  host='127.0.0.1',
                                  database='username_password')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    email = get_valid_email()
    password = input("enter password: ")

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO _info Values (%s,%s)", (email, password))
    cnx.commit()
```

Comment: It dose not work for me in VSCode and add nothing in mysql. Dose it work for you?